# $_SESSION['x'] exist after session_unset(); and session_destroy(); How to remove?

Tags: php

How do I make sure that all `$_SESSION` is removed. I have a page with

```
<?php
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: threads.php");
?>
```

Comment: You forgot session_start()

Comment: Incidentally, the `Location` header should give a full URL, including protocol and domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load/start the session before you can destroy it:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
```